# Is there a way to setup a dynamic htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm need some help with an htaccess rewrite. I would like to do a clean url setup that is dynamic.

For example

```
mydomain.com/pagename/var1/var2/
mydomain.com/pagename2/var1/var2/var3/etc
mydomain.com/pagename3/var1/var2/var3/etc
```

I would like the first level to be alway be the filename in the rewrite?

```
mydomain.com/pagename.php?v1=var1&v2=var2&v3=var3


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$0\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ $0.php?v1=$1&v2=$2&v3=$v3 [L]
```

Comment: are you trying to generate v1=var1, v1=var2, v1=var3,v1=var.............

Comment: at-list tell me that kind of link you want?

Comment: IF you generate in var1, v1=var2, v1=var3..... you can not do only .htaccess, you need .php

Answer (score 1):

This will do your job done,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 

RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule ^home/{0,1}$  pagename.php?v1=1[QSA,L] 

RewriteRule ^sone/{0,1}$  pagename.php?v1=2[QSA,L] 

RewriteRule ^music/{0,1}$  pagename.php?v1=3[QSA,L] 

RewriteRule ^video/{0,1}$  pagename.php?v1=3[QSA,L] 

</IfModule>
```

and the link look like that: [mydomain.com/home](http://#) but the real link is [mydomain.com/pagename.php?v1=1](http://#)